# Could not get the Express route path using node.js and Angular.js

Tags: node.js, express, router

I am not getting the external path while using node.js with the front end. My code is below:

app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
module.exports = router;
```

public/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="SSMS">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Chinmaya Sahu">
    <title>...:::WELCOME:::...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/angularjslatest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/angularuirouterlatest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


<div  ui-view>

</div>
    <script src="/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/controller/dashboardController.js"></script>
    <!--<base href="/cab/admin/"> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here my issue is in `index.html` the external files are not coming. Here I need to access those files present inside `public/javascript` path.

Comment: Watch the case of the path.

Comment: @RolandStarke: Did not get you.

Comment: Sry, I mean, JavaScript has capital leters but in your path the letters are lowercase.

Comment: @RolandStarke: path is `public/javascript`.

Comment: Is the public folder inside the `route` folder? because in `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');` it looks like the file is searched in `routes/public/` But in `app.js` the files are searched in `public/`

Answer (score 0):

you are setting `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));` and i think your index.html is in the public folder, so in the route you dont need to use `__dirname` like this `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');` . I think the right way is `res.sendFile('index.html');`